# Undefined methods issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to modify a form with a dropdown menu filled with values coming from a table named teacher_occupations.

During the whole process, I got inspiration from another form dropdown, doing the same thing but with regions.

Here is the form code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :region_id, class: 'form-label form-label--required' %>
      <%= form.collection_select :region_id, available_regions, :id, :name, { prompt: true }, class: 'form-control form-control--select dropdownSelect' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :teacher_occupation_id, class: 'form-label form-label--required' %>
      <%= form.collection_select :teacher_occupation_id, available_teacher_occupations, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, class: 'form-control form-control--select dropdownSelect' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I run the webpage, I have an *undefined method `teacher_occupation_id' for #* error.

I tried outputting the instance methods of the view with *TeacherCoordinates.new.methods - Object.new.methods*
and I can see region_id, teacher_occupation, but no teacher_occupation_id.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is your entire view?
If yes, try t o use this notation:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: This is an extract. I have a form_for surrounding the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
<%= form.label :teacher_occupation_id, class: 'form-label form-label--required' %>
<%= form.collection_select :teacher_occupation_id, available_teacher_occupations, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, class: 'form-control form-control--select dropdownSelect' %>
```

to

```
<%= form.label :teacher_occupation, class: 'form-label form-label--required' %>
<%= form.collection_select :teacher_occupation, available_teacher_occupations, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, class: 'form-control form-control--select dropdownSelect' %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The way dropdown are implemented use numbers that are the id's in the teacher_occupations table.